# Java ChangeListener firing multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

I have a simple changelistener on a slider. Can anyone explain why it is fired 3 times when I click on a new position.  Before I write code to save the prior value off somewhere to see if it really changed I'd like to find out if there is another way to figure it out.  The first tigger shows it as what it was, the next shows the new value the last repeats the new value.

```
        slider_1 = new JSlider();
    slider_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            if (fullyInitialized == 1) {
                if (comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex() < 1) {
                    SendData2Device(1);     
                }       
            }
        }
    });
    slider_1.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSlider knob not updating (basic Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005488/jslider-knob-not-updating-basic-java). Inside `ChangeListener` you must check `if (!slider.getValueIsAdjusting())`, as this method is called as the value changes and  thus if value is changed 10 times it will be called 10 times

Answer (score 5):

You need to check to see if the change is value adjusting.

Link to the full tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html

But here's the important bit:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
    if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        // Do what needs to occur here.
    }
}
```

Basically when getValueIsAdjusting() returns false, the user has stopped moving the slider.

Comment: Inside the if, where you've said I put what needs doing. I have `System.out.println(sliderValue);` but it is printing twice. I only want it to print once! How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 events as part of the chain in a `ChangeListener`, namely `mouseDown`, `mouseUp` and the change itself.

You can act on the event once the change is complete by using `getValueIsAdjusting`:

```
JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
   ...
}
```

See: [How to Write a Change Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html)